# Image Saving issue from Windows application c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a win apps which save images in a specific folder from where our exe run from. The below I used to save images

```
protected string GetPath(string strFileName)
{
     string strPath=System.Environment.CurrentDirectory+@"\UPS\LabelImages\";
     if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strPath))
     {
          System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);
     }
     strPath = strPath + strFileName;
     return strPath;
}
```

the issue is some time win apps throwing execption like

> *Access to path 'C:\Windows\system32\UPS\LabelImages\' denied*

suppose my application is installed inside `c:\programfiles32` and then throw this kind of error my c# exe file. so tell me what would be the best option to save image files as a result no user get the exception or error like **Access to path 'C:\Windows\system32\UPS\LabelImages\' denied**

Looking for suggestion.

Comment: You also don't need to check if directory exists, `CreateDirectory` will do that for you, so you can just call it every time.

Comment: i do not want to create directory if exist one.

Comment: Of course it won't create it if it already exists, but it won't give an error either, so no need to check.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen r u trying to say CreateDirectory() will not create directory if it exist ?

Comment: "Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend saving those files in a safer location, such as the special folder for application data:

```
var safeFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                       Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"UPS\LabelImages");
```

From the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) doc:

> ApplicationData: The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.

You could easily use another location too, as you see fit (i.e. `MyDocuments` or `MyPictures`).

Some locations on disk are a bad place to try saving files because of the potential for access errors like you're seeing, such as "System32", "Program Files", or the root C: directory, among others.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to run your program as Administrator. 
To do so try to add this line in Properties/app.manifest file:

```
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected string GetPath(string strFileName)
{
     string strPath=Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"\UPS\LabelImages\"  + strFileName);
     return strPath;
}
```